# Duplicate records are being inserted into tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to implement the shopping cart in my project. I found a tutorial and everything works fine, but when I click on *"place oder"* it insert a duplicate record into the following  tables: customers, orders, order_detail.

```
<?php
    include("includes/db.php");
    include("includes/functions.php");

    if($_REQUEST['command']=='update'){
        $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
        $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
        $address=$_REQUEST['address'];
        $phone=$_REQUEST['phone'];

        $result=mysql_query("insert into customers values('','$name','$email','$address','$phone')");
        $customerid=mysql_insert_id();
        $date=date('Y-m-d');
        $result=mysql_query("insert into orders values('','$date','$customerid')");
        $orderid=mysql_insert_id();

        $max=count($_SESSION['cart']);
        for($i=0;$i<$max;$i++){
            $pid=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['productid'];
            $q=$_SESSION['cart'][$i]['qty'];
            $price=get_price($pid);
            mysql_query("insert into order_detail values ($orderid,$pid,$q,$price)");
        }
        die('Thank You! your order has been placed!');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Billing Info</title>
<script language="javascript">
    function validate(){
        var f=document.form1;
        if(f.name.value==''){
            alert('Your name is required');
            f.name.focus();
            return false;
        }
        f.command.value='update';
        f.submit();
    }
</script>
</head>


<body>
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
    <div align="center">
        <h1 align="center">Billing Info</h1>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="2px">
            <tr><td>Order Total:</td><td><?php echo get_order_total()?></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Your Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="name" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address:</td><td><input type="text" name="address" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" /></td></tr>
            <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Place Order" /></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope someone can advise. I went through the code, but I couldn't find what is causing this behavior.

Comment: Your code hasn't got any checks in place that would even attempt checking whether there were any duplicates in the database. You also haven't posted your db structure, but you apparently didn't set any unique constraints that would prevent duplicates from occurring. Also, where did you find that tutorial? It taught you some terrible practices, don't follow it.

Comment: **Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.**  You *really* should be using prepared statements, into which you pass your variables as parameters that do not get evaluated for SQL.  If you don't know what I'm talking about, or how to fix it, read the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Also please stop writing new code with the ancient MySQL extension: it is no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should use either the improved [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) extension or the [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your valuable replies and help, I solved it by removing the below line from the code and it worked.

```
f.submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Off the cuff, your validation function submits as well as the form.  In your validation, change the f.submit(); to return true;

Comment: I return it to to true but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

It is possible looking at your code for user to save transaction twice cos of your validation cos when you submit if($_REQUEST['command']=='update') will be true and an attempt will be made to insert data.
Another reason could be user refreshing the page or clicking upload button more than once. hence u might wanna unset $_REQUEST['command'] when insert is complete. 
Let us know if that works. (mark as answer if correct)

Comment: I tried to unset the $_REQUEST['command'] but also nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think you would want to use another validation technique.
Like I said before, your code is written in such a way that when the user click the 'place order' button, a validation (javascript) is triggered which produces an alert statement and still sends a message. I have modified a better solution of your validation code (mark as correct answer if it works)

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    function validate(){ 
        var f=document.form1; 
        if(f.name.value==''){ 
            alert('Your name is required'); 
            f.name.focus(); 
            return false; 
        } 
else
{
        f.command.value='update'; 
        f.submit();
} 
    } 
</script>
```